# Excel addin is not appearing in Excel online through Admin center

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

We have developed Excel add-in using OfficeJS. We usually used to load Manifest through Office Admin center for sample deployment testing both in Excel Desktop and Online versions.

Actual Output :

We were not able to find add-in  in Excel online version even Manifest file uploaded in admin center.
But same able to find the add-in in Excel Desktop version.

Expected Output :

Once Manifest file uploaded in Office Admin center, add-in should appear in both Excel Online and Desktop versions.

Kindly suggest anything need to check.

Comment: Hi team, any update on this?

Comment: Hi team,  we are waiting reply ASAP since we are in middle of deployment testing of enable/disable ribbon commands features... Or Kindly let me know if am not making clear the clarification...

Comment: Hi team, any update please?

Answer (score 0):

Even though we didn't receive any response but we could able to resolve the issue by clearing cache from beginning date then add-in got appeared as custom tab as expected in Excel online...

Comment: Hi Team, Again we are facing the problem like on every day we have to clear all cache to reflect add-in to appear in Excel tab which was uploaded in admin center for Excel online testing. Kindly help on priority since this problem we are having for long, Also kindly let me know if I am not making clear about the problem....

Comment: Hi Team, Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue we have seen in past if you have multiple sessions running in a browser at the same time. You can try clearing cookies for **"All Time"**,relaunch browser and login again and try. If issue still persist,Kindly share the fiddler trace at addin-help@outlook.com.

Here are the steps to get fiddler trace

1. Install Fiddler.(https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) Close ALL applications. Launch fiddler:
2. Close ALL applications.
3. Launch fiddler:
   ->Go to: Tools -> Options… -> HTTPS
   ->Enable "Decrypt HTTPS traffic"
4. Open Excel Web on browser
5. Click on OfficeAddins in the excel ribbon and then click on Admin Managed as shown in screenshot
   [image]
6. Save the Fiddler trace: Go to File -> Save -> All Sessions.
7. Share the Fiddler trace file (*.saz) as attachment over email.